# Center a bootstrap 4 navbar (including brand and links)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a bit struggling to center the navbar of my website (including the brand and the links) since I'm more of a backend than front.

**Code**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**What I want**

I know that I can center the links using `m-auto` but the brand (which has an image as a logo) would stay to the left and I can't seem to figure out how to center it with the links (in a good/clean way).

Thank you.

None of the links referenced as duplicate helps me. I need the brand logo AND the links in the center, the links ZimSystem gave only do one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.brand-wrapper{
   width:100%;
}


.navbar-toggler{
float:left;
}



@media(max-width: 767px){

.navbar-brand{
 left:50%;
 position:absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%);
}

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  

    <div class="brand-wrapper">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-center" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-center disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Doesn't this only center it in mobile? I was talking about the normal view (desktops etc) :/

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
<style>
li{
text-align:center;
border:2px solid white;
}
li:hover{
background-color:silver;
box-shadow:inset 0px 3px 5px 0px grey;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
}
.navbar-brand{
float:left !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

plz try

Comment: i thing this is proper way to operate nav for mobile device middle having proble if brand name is big if you want you can just remove css                                   
              brand-nav{ float:left;}

Comment: I am not sure this works..

Comment: i am not understanding what you want to say